# Identify who triggered a function

Tags: javascript, function, events, triggers, onkeyup

I have a question, not sure how to achieve this using Javascript.

I have a page with for example 2 input fields, right now, what I'm doing is "onKeyUp" calling a function and passing a parameter of who is calling the function.

Is there any way to just call the function, and from within the function know what field called it?

Example:

```
<input name="q1" id="q1" onkeyup="mirar('q1')" type="text" />
<input name="q2" id="q2" onkeyup="mirar('q2')" type="text" />
```

Change it into something like

```
<input name="q1" id="q1" onkeyup="mirar()" type="text" />
<input name="q2" id="q2" onkeyup="mirar()" type="text" />
```

Comment: *"Is there any way to just call the function, and from within the function know what field called it?"* No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass `this` to refer that in the function to know from which element the function is actually called:

```js
function mirar(el){
  console.log('Id:', el.id)
}
```

```html
<input name="q1" id="q1" onkeyup="mirar(this)" type="text" />
<input name="q2" id="q2" onkeyup="mirar(this)" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 1):

[EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup) should provide what you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
function mirar()
{
    alert("caller is " + mirar.caller);
}
```

Or, would it be acceptable if they still passed a parameter, but the same parameter?

```
<input name="q1" id="q1" onkeyup="mirar(event)" type="text" />
<input name="q2" id="q2" onkeyup="mirar(event)" type="text" />

function mirar(event) { 
    alert(event.target.nodeName);
}
```

Comment: The first won't give you the input field element though.